# SQL Rows to Columns, PIVOT probably would work but not sure how with multiple columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I've got a poorly designed table, that has a mixture of rows and columns, where it probably should have had 1 row with many many columns or some other design entirely. But that mistake was 20 years ago, on someone else's watch.

Right now I'm accomplishing the view I want with a myriad of self-joins.  This is painfully slow.

The following will set up how I'm doing at the moment:

```
declare @client table
(
    clientNumber int,
    name    varchar(10)
)

insert into @client values (1, 'Bob');
insert into @client values (2, 'Alice');

declare @options table
(
    clientNumber int,
    optionKey varchar(4),
    optionValue1 int,
    optionValue2 int,
    optionValue3 int
)
insert into @options values (1, 'optA', 1, 1, 0);
insert into @options values (1, 'optB', 0, 1, 0);
insert into @options values (2, 'optA', 1, 1, 1);
insert into @options values (2, 'optC', 0, 0, 1);

select c.clientNumber, c.name, 
        oA.optionValue1 as [Graduated], 
        oA.optionValue2 as [Employed], 
        oA.optionValue3 as [Married], 
        oB.optionValue1 as [HasPets], 
        oB.optionValue2 as [LikesThai], 
        oB.optionValue3 as [MathWiz], 
        oC.optionValue1 as [DrvLicense], 
        oC.optionValue2 as [Registered], 
        oC.optionValue3 as [Outdoorsy] 
    from @client c
    left outer join @options oA 
        on oA.clientNumber = c.clientNumber and oA.optionKey = 'optA'
    left outer join @options oB 
        on oB.clientNumber = c.clientNumber and oB.optionKey = 'optB'
    left outer join @options oC 
        on oC.clientNumber = c.clientNumber and oC.optionKey = 'optC'
```

For these results:

[image: result set from above query]

The result set is exactly what I want.  Not every client has an A, B, or C record so the `null` in the result set is fine.  I can't find an example like this after a while of searching so I'm not sure `PIVOT` is really what I'm looking for.  Suggestions?

Update:
this seems to produce the same results.  I'm going to test it on the much larger case to see if it's faster than all of the self-joins.  (I suspect it is).  I'd still like to know if I'm barking up the wrong tree with pivots.

```
select clientNumber,
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optA' then o.optionValue1 end) [Graduated],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optA' then o.optionValue2 end) [Employed],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optA' then o.optionValue3 end) [Married],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optB' then o.optionValue1 end) [HasPets],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optB' then o.optionValue2 end) [LikesThai],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optB' then o.optionValue3 end) [MathWix],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optC' then o.optionValue1 end) [DrvLicense],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optC' then o.optionValue2 end) [Registered],
    Min(Case o.optionKey when 'optC' then o.optionValue3 end) [Outdoorsy]
    from @options o
    group by clientnumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.  Both solutions use a technique that pivots the data.  The first solution will change your NULLs to 0.

```
SELECT c.clientNumber, c.name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN o.optionValue1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Graduated], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN o.optionValue2 ELSE 0 END) AS [Employed], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN o.optionValue3 ELSE 0 END) AS [Married], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN o.optionValue1 ELSE 0 END) AS [HasPets], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN o.optionValue2 ELSE 0 END) AS [LikesThai], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN o.optionValue3 ELSE 0 END) AS [MathWiz], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN o.optionValue1 ELSE 0 END) AS [DrvLicense], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN o.optionValue2 ELSE 0 END) AS [Registered], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN o.optionValue3 ELSE 0 END) AS [Outdoorsy] 
FROM @client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN @options o 
    ON o.clientNumber = c.clientNumber
GROUP BY c.clientNumber, c.name
ORDER BY c.clientNumber, c.name
```

The second solution preserves the NULL values.  However, it requires an explicit type conversion from BIT to TINYINT, because the MAX function fails on BIT data types.

```
SELECT c.clientNumber, c.name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN CAST (o.optionValue1 AS TINYINT) END) AS [Graduated], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN CAST (o.optionValue2 AS TINYINT) END) AS [Employed], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optA' THEN CAST (o.optionValue3 AS TINYINT) END) AS [Married], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN CAST (o.optionValue1 AS TINYINT) END) AS [HasPets], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN CAST (o.optionValue2 AS TINYINT) END) AS [LikesThai], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optB' THEN CAST (o.optionValue3 AS TINYINT) END) AS [MathWiz], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN CAST (o.optionValue1 AS TINYINT) END) AS [DrvLicense], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN CAST (o.optionValue2 AS TINYINT) END) AS [Registered], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.optionKey = 'optC' THEN CAST (o.optionValue3 AS TINYINT) END) AS [Outdoorsy] 
FROM @client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN @options o 
    ON o.clientNumber = c.clientNumber
GROUP BY c.clientNumber, c.name
ORDER BY c.clientNumber, c.name
```

Comment: Ahh, I'll probably go with something like this.  And I made a mistake in the @options table above, those really should have been `int`s (of one sort or another) instead of `bit`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about its performance, but I would do it this way:

```
select c.clientNumber, c.name, 
    oA.optionValue1 as [Graduated], 
    oA.optionValue2 as [Employed], 
    oA.optionValue3 as [Married], 
    oB.optionValue1 as [HasPets], 
    oB.optionValue2 as [LikesThai], 
    oB.optionValue3 as [MathWiz], 
    oC.optionValue1 as [DrvLicense], 
    oC.optionValue2 as [Registered], 
    oC.optionValue3 as [Outdoorsy] 
from @client c 
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optA' And clientnumber = c.clientnumber) oA
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optB' And clientnumber = c.clientnumber) oB
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optC' And clientnumber = c.clientnumber) oC
```

or CTE might be useful

```
with t as
(select oA.ClientNumber, 
    oA.optionValue1 as [Graduated], 
    oA.optionValue2 as [Employed], 
    oA.optionValue3 as [Married], 
    oB.optionValue1 as [HasPets], 
    oB.optionValue2 as [LikesThai], 
    oB.optionValue3 as [MathWiz], 
    oC.optionValue1 as [DrvLicense], 
    oC.optionValue2 as [Registered], 
    oC.optionValue3 as [Outdoorsy] 
from 
     (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optA') oA
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optB' And clientnumber = oA.clientnumber) oB
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @options WHERE optionkey = 'optC' And clientnumber = oA.clientnumber) oC )

 select c.clientNumber, c.name,
    t.[Graduated], 
    t.[Employed], 
    t.[Married], 
    t.[HasPets], 
    t.[LikesThai], 
    t.[MathWiz], 
    t.[DrvLicense], 
    t.[Registered], 
    t.[Outdoorsy] 
from @client c join t on c.clientnumber = t.clientnumber
```

Comment: I think performance hit is on the repeated self-joins.  (BTW, the real life table has about 15 "optionkey" values and the table has about 100,000 records.)

Comment: How about using a temporary table or create an index view ?

Comment: Currently, this mess is installed in a view.  But a temp table (or view) doesn't solve the problem of how to get things into the table without multiple passes over the data set.

Comment: for me 100 000 doesn't sound that big number if you have optimal indexes it should not take long time to run...